# Apply stroke only to top layer of clipping mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, mask, stroke

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CC. I have a clipping mask with text over colored rectangles. I want to apply stroke to the text in the clipping mask without applying stroke to the rectangles. This is what happens:

[image: text over rectangles]

I apply the clipping mask:

[image: text clipping mask]

I apply the stroke:

[image: clipping mask with stroke]

and now you see the rectangles also have stroke applied. How to I make it so only the text has a stroke? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to select the paths of the clipping mask and add a stroke to them. Do **not** use the Selection Tool (black arrow).

[image]

I'd just use a gradient with middle stops as an extra fill on text objects, allowing the text to remain "live" and editable.

[image]

This is easiest with single lines of text, but the gradient can be configured for multi-line text as well. Save this as a **Graphic Style** and it can be applied to any text with two clicks.

Comment: Thank you! This is a fantastic response, and not only solved my problem, but taught me things as well. Much appreciated!